# How to set the time sink to roll mode like oscilloscope?

Tags: gnuradio

How to set the time sink to roll mode like oscilloscope? The signal rolls in from the right side of the oscilloscope screen and rolls out from the left side so that we can see the complete picture of the signal.Instead of focusing on signal segments that meet specific conditions as in trigger mode.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That functionality has not been implemented.

Comment: Understood, thank you. I found GNURADIO a week ago and it's a great platform. I am studying the Intermediate Tutorials. Amazing!

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, sorry the answer was not any more positive - it's just that this is one of the things we never gotten around to implement